# How can i access to the other scipts in the scene when i use Dontdestroyonload( ) function

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Body<>

void Start(){

Dondestroy(this.gameobject`enter code here`);
}

Comment: Can you provide some more concrete details? How to access other scripts in a scene is the same with or without DontDestroyOnLoad.

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. The code you posted doesn't make any sense, and your question lacks details and precision.

Answer (score 0):

You should use FindObjectsOfType, or reference the other scripts you need to use.